# redirect to another form after few second in window application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 form in application and I want to change form after few second..and again come back to first form..just like slideshow.

Is it possible to do with timer ? Or I need to add anything more

Comment: You may find another good posts about this on SO. BTW I answered a question a few days ago that it's code may be useful for you. Have a look at it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457610/timer-wont-stop-after-being-stopped-or-disabled

Comment: but the problem is I have already another form in my application and in your code u have created new form at run time..can I show my existing form ?

Comment: It just created an instance of existing form. Of course you can show your existing form but you need to create an instance of it first (replace `Form1 ` with your form's name) then show it, like the example.

Answer (score 1):

Sound to me like a classic use of a [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) in your forms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you are trying to accomplish this in, but in C# you can use a timer for this no problem.

Take a look at System.Timers.Timer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or you could also use System.Windows.Forms.Timer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To open the form as you like you can use the **.ShowDialog();** method.
from there you can have a timer set to close the dialog.